# Is there something wrong with my usage of Symbol.isConcatSpreadable in babel?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Recently I'm learning ES2015(ES6) with `Babel`, and I found `Symbol.isConcatSpreadable` is not work correctly for me. As of ES6 the way `Array#concat` will determine if any of its arguments are spreadable will be with `Symbol.isConcatSpreadable`. Here's my test code:

```
let arr1 = [3, 4];
console.log(arr1[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable]);
console.log([1, 2].concat(arr1, 5));

let arr2 = [3, 4];
arr2[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable] = false;
console.log([1, 2].concat(arr2, 5));
```

As of ES2015(ES6) the output should be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, [3, 4], 5]
```

But I found the result with `Babel` is:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

It seems that `Babel` does not transform correctly.
My `package.json` file:

```
{
  ...,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.6.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-node": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-instanceof": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.6.1"
  },
  ...
}
```

My `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets":[
    "node"
  ],
  "plugins":[
    "transform-runtime",
    "transform-es2015-instanceof"
  ]
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code or am I missing a certain babel plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel does not transpile things like `arr1[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable]`, it just returns the same code `arr1[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable]`, and hence such code is dependent on Symbol polyfill.

From the [Babel JS site about **Symbol**](http://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#symbols):

> Limited support via polyfill
>   Limited support requires the Babel polyfill. Due to language limitations, some features can't be transpiled or polyfilled. See core.js's caveats section for more details.

Furthermore from the [GitHub page of **Symbol polyfill**](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#missing-polyfills):

> ES6 logic for @@isConcatSpreadable and @@species (in most places) can be polyfilled without problems, but it will cause a serious slowdown in popular cases in some engines. It will be polyfilled when it will be implemented in modern engines.

So in short, you cannot provide cross-browser support for **isConcatSpreadable** using *babel* for now (latest by March 19, 2016), but if you target is some of the latest browsers like Chrome and Edge, where Symbol polyfill is not needed, the code will work as it is, like in the following snippet (if you run it in chrome).

```js
let arr1 = [3, 4];
log([1, 2].concat(arr1, 5));

let arr2 = [3, 4];
arr2[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable] = false;
log([1, 2].concat(arr2, 5));

function log (data) {
  document.writeln(JSON.stringify(data) + "<br/>");
}
```

**Update**:

There is another thing that you can do, if you can override the default functionality of `Array.prototype.concat` to support `Symbol.isConcatSpreadable`, then your code would work.